# cannot download "pecl/mongodb"

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, pecl

I'm new trying to install mongodb on CentOS residing on Vagrant. Mongo is installed but when I try to install mongodb is gives some errors, following is the behavior:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# pecl install mongodb
PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
downloading mongodb-1.2.9.tgz ...
Starting to download mongodb-1.2.9.tgz (786,049 bytes)    
..............................................................done: 
786,049 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from 
"/tmp/pear/download/mongodb-1.2.9.tgz"
Download of "pecl/mongodb" succeeded, but it is not a valid package 
archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/mongodb"
Download failed
install failed
[root@localhost vagrant]#
```

After trying many hours following different links, I'm finally here. Please suggest what's going wrong.

Comment: Please add your provisioning script or commands you're using to install mongo.

Comment: @RandallFlagg, It's "pecl install mongo"